# Im new to set operators and dont exactly get how they work or why

Tags: sql-server

so im trying to complete this question

```
Using a Set Operator, create a query that will show the names of those teams that have not won a
game. Include in your output the team name. Your output should look like the following:
teamName
---------------
No Winner
Red Tigers
```

i tried a buncha different stuff such as

```
select teamName
from team
intersect
select winning_team
from game;
```

but to be honest i dont even think im close, 
and i have no idea how to do it, i can get the teamids to show up that won games, but i dont know how to make it show the ids that did not win games, and even if i could i dont know how to convert the number into the name of the team, i always get an error, im dying here this was an in class assignment that she assigned as homework instead and usually i would have the teacher to help explain this stuff... :( if anyones willing to help that would be great

i ended up using this

```
select teamName
from team
except
select teamName
from team t join game g
    on g.winning_team = t.teamID;
```

thank you dstanley for the nudge i needed

Comment: We NOT going to do your homework for you. What would happen when you have to do this on the job? We can help nudge you but this is something you should be able to figure out with your book.

Comment: `NOT IN` and `NOT EXISTS` would both work for you.  Look those up, take a stab at applying them, and come back with specific problems.

Comment: thanks for replies, wasnt exactly asking you to do my homework, just needed a push in the right direction, my biggest problem is the error i keep getting where   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'No Winner      ' to data type int.

Comment: @DStanley the homework question specifically states Set operator. This means EXCEPT or INTERSECT. To the OP, consider a query that returns all team names except those you don't want.

Comment: thank you dstanley, i think i have it now, i got the number to convert and i am going to use the except

Comment: I guess `EXCEPT` would work too.  I don't use that one too much,